# ConflictingBeanDefinitionException : Same class name, different package

Tags: java, spring

I have a dao in one package:

```
package com.mypackage.dao;

@Repository
public class MyDao {
// some code here
}
```

I have another dao with same class name in a sub package:

```
package com.mypackage.one.dao;

@Repository
public class MyDao {
// some other code here
}
```

I have third class where I am trying to inject the bean using autowiring:

```
import com.mypackage.one.dao;

public class TestClass{

@Autowired
private MyDao myDao;

}
```

On deployment, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'myDao' for bean class [com.mypackage.dao.MyDao] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.mypackage.one.dao.MyDao]
```

My applicationContext.xml has:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.one.dao"/>
```

I can not rename the classes as its a legacy application.

What is the solution for this ?

I tried using qualifier, but that is not working.

Added below line:

```
<bean id="oneMyDao" class="com.mypackage.one.dao.MyDao" />
```

And changed autowiring to:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("oneMyDao")
private MyDao myDao;
```

But it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your mixing  XML and Java bean configuration for same bean.
your code should be something like this

```
package com.mypackage.dao;
@Repository
@Qualifier("myDAOBasePackage")
public class MyDao
{
// some code here
}



   package com.mypackage.one.dao;

    @Repository
    @Qualifier("myDAOSubPackage")
    public class MyDao {
    // some other code here
    }
```

Ues this to inject

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myDAOBasePackage")
private MyDao myDao;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in definition of beans. You have to give your beans different names.

Please, try to change annotations to `@Repository("dao1")` for the first dao and to `@Repository("dao2")` for the second dao. And then try to `@Autowire` bean using `@Qualifier("dao1")` or `@Qualifier("dao2")`.

Also you should remove this line

```
<bean id="oneMyDao" class="com.mypackage.one.dao.MyDao" />
```

if you use `@Repository` annotation